# Go REST API endpoint and Encoded parameters?

Tags: rest, go, web-development-server

I'm still new to Go (and web programming in general) so apologies if I don't explain things properly.

I need my server to listen out for POST requests which will have four parameters. "Your REST API should expect the following parameters."

```
id int
con_id  string
key  string
fields  array
```

An example request would be:

```
uid=5&con_id=3456&key=6nD1a7EATbP7ewmZCpNkxzzyMvuIKqQQ&fields%5Bfield_ds_personal_details%5D%5B0%5D%5B%5D%5Baccess%5D%5Br%5D%5Ba%5D=1&fields%5Bfield_ds_personal_details%5D%5B0%5D%5B%5D%5Baccess%5D%5Br%5D%5Bs%5D=A
```

I'm unsure however how to properly do this in Go.

I've been using my endpoint as

```
api/user/{id}/{con_id}/{key}/{fields}
```

I can get it to work if I POST to

```
api/user/5/3456/hhjdd7887334jf but that's not how their API makes the request.
```

Using Postman and adding the parameters (so they're the same, encoded in the way the should be) I get a 404.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Even if it's just somewhere I can read more about how parameters in a request work.

Comment: If the endpoint is `api/user/`, that's the route that should be registered in whatever mux you're using. If you need to accept POST parameters, you need to read those, not URL parameters - that entire avenue is a red herring. If you're using the standard library's HTTP handlers, you can read POST data using [`Request.ParseForm`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much. I think I've got it working now. I had been trying to use ` params := mux.Vars(r)`  like I'd been using when setting things up. Parsing the request using ` request.URL`  seems to have worked.